# Convert a MySQL database from latin to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I am converting a website from ISO to UTF-8, so I need to convert the MySQL database too.

On the Internet, I read various solutions, I don't know which one to choose.

Do I really need to convert my varchar columns to binary, then to UTF-8 like that:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col BINARY(150);
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col CHAR(150) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

It takes a long time to do that for each column, of each table, of each database.

I have 10 databases, with 20 tables each, with around 2 - 3 varchar columns (2 queries each column), this gives me around **1000 queries to write**! How to do it?

**Resolved** :
I post the code that I have used:

```
PASSWORD=""
db=$1

mysqldump --password=$PASSWORD --set-charset --skip-set-charset --add-drop-table --databases "$db" > /home/dev/backup/bdd.sql

QUERY="ALTER DATABASE \`$db\` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;"
mysql --password=$PASSWORD --database "$db" -e "$QUERY"

mysql --password=$PASSWORD --default-character-set=utf8 < /home/dev/backup/bdd.sql
```

See the answer below for more information.

Comment: Aren't `--set-charset` and `--skip-set-charset` directly competing flags? Docs say they affect the use of `SET NAMES`, but doesn't set the `DEFAULT CHARSET=X` parameter that is output via `mysqldump` per table. (mysql 5.5)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do that very easily using a dump. Make a dump using

```
mysqldump --skip-opt --set-charset --skip-set-charset
```

Then create another database, set its default character set to UTF-8 and then load your dump back with:

```
mysql --default-character-set=<your iso encoding>
```

The main idea is to make a dump without any sign of data encoding.
So, at create time, the table's encoding would be inherit from the database encoding and set to UTF-8. And with `--default-character-set` we tell MySQL to recode our data automatically.

Comment: Oh this seems nice ! Why isn't that on the documentation, or nobody talks about that anywhere, thanks I will test it

Comment: @Matthieu as it seems you're going to make it with `--all-databases`, please make it with precautions. Make a backup and  test whole algorithm on one database first.

Comment: Well I just tested (on one database only, to be sure) and this doesn't change the encoding of the columns (they are still in "latin"). Just to be sure, for the mysqldump, the 3 parameters don't need values ?

Comment: @Matthieu this is actually 2 parameters, as far as I understand. `--skip-opt --set-charset` tell database not to add default charset clause to the table definitions. And `--skip-set-charset` remove `SET NAMES` query from the top of the dump. How do you know of data encoding? utf-8 is very similar to latin1 What does it say of table encoding if you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` for the new table?  is there any character sets in the dump? Do you name `utf8` properly (as it differ from usual `utf-8`)

Comment: Thanks I've got it working. What I had to do is dump, empty the database (drop tables, BUT KEEP DATABASE), set its encoding to UTF8, then re-import the content. Then the content is fully UTF8, else it doesn't work fully. I've posted the code above, in my question.

Comment: WARNING : I found out (the hard way) that the "--skip-opt" parameter makes the create table queries not include the auto_increment statement ! (http://groups.google.com/group/comp.databases.mysql/browse_thread/thread/01ccba8f07dc65fc?pli=1) (I don't blame you though, I should have tested more)

Comment: BTW, the above command does not work. MySQL (5.1) will continue to dump `CHARACTER SET latin1` at *column* level.

Comment: Run the SQL files produced by mysqldump through "iconv -f <your iso encoding> -t utf8" before importing them.

Comment: Works for me. I used it on a Windows machine and tested some tables having latin1_swedish_ci before in a full utf-8 environement (Database, database stream, php settings and php file). Everything looks good.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using mysqldump  Ver 10.11 Distrib 5.0.77

For some reason create options Engine and auto_increment was omitted. This caused a lot of insert errors, because auto_increment was gone on primary key fields.

This worked for me. I'm using --opt and using sed to remove charset from sql file.

```
mysqldump -p --opt --skip-set-charset --add-drop-table dbname > /tmp/dbname.sql
sed -i 's/DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1//g' /tmp/dbname.sql 
ALTER DATABASE dbname DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_danish_ci;
mysql -p --default-character-set=utf8 db < /tmp/dbname.sql
```

Comment: As Mysql 5.5 will output `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`, which the `--default-character-set=utf8` won't overwrite on import, this step becomes necessary. I used `sed -i 's/DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1/DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8/g' /tmp/dbname.sql` to explicitly set it to utf8.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqldump --opt --skip-set-charset --default-character-set='latin1' -u root -p revive_adserver --result-file='dump.sql'

vim dump.sql

:%s/latin1/utf8/gi

:wq

mysql -u root -p

ALTER DATABASE revive_adserver CHARACTER SET utf8;

\q

mysql -D revive_adserver -u root -p < dump.sql
```