# Greek text encoding after website moving to new server

Tags: php, character-encoding, cs-cart

Recently Ive decided to change the server I was using and move one of my clients website to my private server. The old server had PHP Version 5.x and MySQL Version 5.x the same with the new one. Unfortunately the Greek encoding crashed. I checked the collation of the MySQL but nothing has changed. The Website is using cs-cart. I am newbie with PHP and I cant find a way to fix the problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809320/php-mysql-utf-8-some-characters-are-still-bug and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543993/convert-a-mysql-database-from-latin-to-utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

How did you restore the database? If it was restored with the server tools, try to restore the database again with built-in CS-Cart Backup/ Restore feature. It should solve the issue.

Note: Do not not edit backup in any text editor.